# Recursive function using volley out of memory error

Tags: java, android, recursion, android-volley, stack-overflow

I am using Volley library to communicate with my database. I use recursive function to check continuously my database but after a period of time seems like the recursive function stop working and I get the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.sakis.loginregister, PID: 22637
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (stack size 131072 bytes) failed: Try again
     at java.lang.VMThread.create(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1029)
     at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:145)
     at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:66)
     at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)
     at com.example.sakis.loginregister.MultiPlayerActivity.func(MultiPlayerActivity.java:342)
     at com.example.sakis.loginregister.MultiPlayerActivity$2.onResponse(MultiPlayerActivity.java:160)
     at com.example.sakis.loginregister.MultiPlayerActivity$2.onResponse(MultiPlayerActivity.java:133)
     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think it is a stackoverflow error when i dont get the proper response in time.Here is the recursive function code that i first call in onCreate method:

```
void func(){

    reject=0;
    Response.Listener<String> response1Listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(final String response) {


            try {


                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                request = jsonResponse.getInt("request");
                requestorigin = jsonResponse.getString("requestorigin");
                category = jsonResponse.getInt("category");
                dif_level = jsonResponse.getInt("dif_level");
                number_of_questions = jsonResponse.getInt("number_of_questions");
                time_of_answer = jsonResponse.getInt("time_of_answer");

                if(request==0)  {





                    func();

                }

                if (request == 1) {



                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MultiPlayerActivity.this,R.style.myBackgroundStyle);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Έχεις νέο αίτημα από τον χρήστη " + requestorigin + "\n" + "Κατηγορία Ερωτήσεων: " + array_category[category]
                            + "\n" + "Επίπεδο Δυσκολίας: " + array_dif_level[dif_level] + "\n" + "Αριθμός Ερωτήσεων: " + number_of_questions + "\n "
                            + "Χρόνος Απάντησης: " + time_of_answer);

                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ναι", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {


                            Response.Listener<String> response1Listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(final String response) {


                                    try {


                                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);


                                    } catch (JSONException e)

                                    {

                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }


                            };


                            SendResponseRequest sendResponseRequest = new SendResponseRequest(username, response1Listener);
                            RequestQueue queue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(MultiPlayerActivity.this);
                            queue1.add(sendResponseRequest);



                            Response.Listener<String> responseListener=new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                        boolean success1=jsonResponse.getBoolean("success1");
                                        if(success1)  {
                                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MultiPlayerActivity.this, MultiPlayerGame2Activity.class);
                                            intent2.putExtra("username1",username);
                                            intent2.putExtra("username2",requestorigin);
                                            intent2.putExtra("category", category);
                                            intent2.putExtra("dif_level", dif_level);
                                            intent2.putExtra("number_of_questions", number_of_questions);
                                            intent2.putExtra("time_of_answer", time_of_answer);
                                            intent2.putExtra("level", level);
                                            intent2.putExtra("score", score);
                                            intent2.putExtra("music",music);
                                            intent2.putExtra("sound",sound);
                                            startActivity(intent2);
                                            // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                            finish();
                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e)

                                    {

                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }
                            };




                            Back0Request back0Request = new Back0Request(username,responseListener);
                            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MultiPlayerActivity.this);
                            queue.add(back0Request);








                        }
                    });

                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Όχι", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {




                                    Response.Listener<String> response1Listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(final String response) {


                                            try {


                                                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                                reject = jsonResponse.getInt("reject");
                                                if(reject==1)  {
                                                    func();
                                                }

                                            } catch (JSONException e)

                                            {

                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }


                                        }


                                    };


                                    RejectRequestRequest rejectRequestRequest = new RejectRequestRequest(username, response1Listener);
                                    RequestQueue queue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(MultiPlayerActivity.this);
                                    queue1.add(rejectRequestRequest);





                                        }

                    });


                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();




                }





            } catch (JSONException e)

            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    };


    //text2.setText("OK");
    CheckRequest checkRequest = new CheckRequest(username, response1Listener);
    /***
     int socketTimeout = 30000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
     RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
     checkRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
     ******/
    RequestQueue queue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(MultiPlayerActivity.this);
    queue1.add(checkRequest);

    //text3.setText("After ");

}
```

When the variable requests that I take from the database has a zero value I want to check the database again until it will take a non-zero value. Is there any better way to achieve that so I can avoid recursion because it will cause some overflow errors.

Comment: Use a loop with a condition and try only to initialize objects once, outside of the loop (or the recursive function). Recursive calls are often useful for heuristic functions, but this does not seem to be a requirement here. Try to manage the state/s separately outside the loop.

Comment: I had tried while-loop with a condition but the application crashes.That's why i went to recursion to avoid using loops .

Comment: Can you post the error from the loop crash?

Comment: I had tried that and as i said the application crashed in the while loop.So is pointless  to change all the code again to take the error message using loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when i use Singleton Pattern and re-use the same instance of the queue so i prevent out of memory error:

```
public class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static Context mContext;

private MySingleton(Context context){
    // Specify the application context
    mContext = context;
    // Get the request queue
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context){
    // If Instance is null then initialize new Instance
    if(mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    // Return MySingleton new Instance
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
    // If RequestQueue is null the initialize new RequestQueue
    if(mRequestQueue == null){
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    }

    // Return RequestQueue
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public<T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request){
    // Add the specified request to the request queue
    getRequestQueue().add(request);
}
```